# Intellij IDEA деплой на Tomcat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, tomcat

Пытаюсь задеплоить проект на Tomcat.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bitloor</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitloor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Сервлет

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet</h2>");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" >
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bitloor.servlet.MainServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: img]
[image: img]
Но такой кнопки запуска не появилось

[image: img]

Сейчас все выглядит вот так

[image: img]

Что еще необходимо сделать или что не так?

Comment: edit config-n -> в верхнем левом углу нахать + и выбрать Tomcat server -> local [пример](http://croper.ru/images/20170213yxsPSoK0HLL9RMRO_zN67w_large.png) на картинке

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Серьезно? А это что? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mf7n.png

Comment: ага, серьезно. на вашей фото вы настриваете шаблон конфигурации, а на моей нужно из этого шаблона добавить к себе конфигурацию

Comment: Вау, спасибо. Оформите как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы настриваете шаблон конфигурации, а нужно из этого шаблона добавить к себе конфигурацию

edit config-n -> в верхнем левом углу нахать + и выбрать Tomcat server -> local

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]